# Sets, indexes, subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $E$ be a vector space and $X$ contained in $E$.
Say I want to talk about all vector subspaces of $E$ that contain the set $X \subset E$.
I could associate a family of indices $L$ to these subspaces. That is, can I do the placement:

Let $L$ is a set of indices such that $\forall\lambda \in L$, $F_{\lambda}$ is a subspace of $E$ whith $F_{\lambda}\supset X$.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. At worse, let $L$ be the set of all subspaces of $E$ containing $X$. Then you can define $F_\lambda = \lambda$, and you have your set of indices.

You can *always* find a set of indices if you don't have any special restriction on it.

Comment: Hello Captain Lama. Thank you for your answer :)